# Bowerrc post install hook not working

Tags: javascript, frontend, bower

According to [this post](http://hire.chrisjlee.net/node/237) bower should be able to run a postinstall script in versions 1.3.1 and above. I am using bower 1.3.12.

Here's my bowerrc file:

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "./node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt"
    }
}
```

However, when I install the package using bower, the hook does not get executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bower's use of [`scripts` hooks](https://github.com/bower/bower/blob/master/HOOKS.md) are meant for the parent project that depends on components, not for the components themselves. "*These hooks are not intended to provide a post-installation build step for component authors.*" You should be publishing an already-grunted version of your component.

Comment: Isnt it a bad idea to commit built files? I dont want to pollute my repo with a random minified file when the src is already there. (It seems kind of silly to me that the bower authors removed postinstall hooks when npm has them).

Comment: It's maybe not always ideal, but certainly a possibility. Though, they should probably be organized so they don't seem random. Bootstrap, for example, currently keeps a [`/dist` folder](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v3.3.4/dist). And, regarding NPM, it allows this to be resolved with a [`prepublish` script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) and a registry that itself stores published files, so you can publish built files without having to keep them in your repo.

Comment: fair, dont agree with comitting built files whether they are in dist or not. Seems like a hack. `npm prepublish` might be a sort of workaround, but it doesnt help if the package is being published and consumed with bower.

Comment: if Bower decides no new packages need to be installed it doesn't call the postinstall hook

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem as yours. 
I have been resolved by add an variable ***cwd*** to ***.bowerrc*** file:

```
{
  "cwd": "./",  
   "scripts": {
        "postinstall": "grunt wiredep"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple reason is because you don't have any packages in your bower.json or all of the packages have been installed.

Please have a look at my issue reported in github: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/2302